# How do I make firefox work with a macro?

Tags: firefox, macros

I'm using firefox with a form. I'm trying to submit the same page 20 times at the same time. So I fill out the 20 forms, go to firefox, hit offline mode, click ok on all the forms.

It is critical for me for the info to be submitted at the nearly time. So I hit reload all tabs. Now a pop up is created, "confirm", "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

So I set up a macro that spams the button enter every 10ms. However, the marco spams it so hard, that firefox creates a new pop up that is blank, and it says yes or no with two buttons, and if the spamming is continued, firefox will exit. So it's some kind of any input spam mechanism. Any ideas how to get around it?

My task is to get rid of the 20 "to display this page" pop ups at the same time.

Comment: may help if you provided the website url

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with javascript you can try GreaseMonkey to do this task in the browser

For quick start, here you go [GreaseMonkey For Bigenners](http://hayageek.com/greasemonkey-tutorial/)

Comment: perhaps an alternative, perhaps imacros might help